# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't detect my second monitor

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have Ubuntu 16.04 (dual boot with Windows 10) and a HP Spectre x360 laptop.

I have recently bought a Dell Ultrasharp U2515H monitor, which I connect via a Dell docking station.

When I plug the docking station to my laptop on Windows, both monitors are detected and everything works fine.

When I try with Ubuntu, it seems that the second monitor is not detected even when I click "Detect Displays" - I just see my one built in monitor. I think I correctly downloaded the drivers for the Dell docking station, because the external mouse, keyboard and ethernet connection all seem to be working correctly.

Any help to get Ubuntu to detect my second monitor would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

---

The monitor connect to the docking station using a DP cable, and then a SuperSpeed USB 3.0 Type A to B Cable connects the docking station to my laptop.

---

Results of lsusb:

Bus 002 Device 005: ID 17e9:436e DisplayLink
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 17e9:436e DisplayLink
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 04f3:2274 Elan Microelectronics Corp.
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c8c Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 413c:2110 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 413c:1010 Dell Computer Corp.
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hu

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps ubuntu does not support that type of connection port the dock uses to convert all the ports in the back, sorry for the lack of knowledge but from the top of my head that is what I think it is.

Comment: there's a difference between *being polite* and *under-confident*. Be confident enough and answer in a manner that satisfies the questioner.

Answer (score 1):

That dock uses the displaylink driver , you can download it here.
http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

I've used this with a usb2 device and it was annoyingly slow, hopefully its better with your usb3 versions increased bandwidth.

Comment: I have downloaded that driver.  As I mentioned, I think the dock is working okay because the mouse, keyboard and ethernet are all working.

Comment: those devices are just usb devices on a hub , one of the usb devices will be a displaylink adapter.  If the install worked you just plug in  the monitor and it should be visible in the Control Center -> Display Settings. If that doesn't work post the output of the 'lsusb' command.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I will post the results in my question now.